# Не получается найти горячие клавиши в vs code(python) для вывода списка доступных модулей в windows

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Всем привет, изучаю питон, сейчас прохожу тему о встроенных модулях.
Можно узнать список встроенных модулей с помощью help('modules'), но как узнать список всех доступных модулей при помощи горячих клавиш?
В примере было:
import  <-тут после пробела и комбинации клавиш (alt+esc на маке) выпадает список доступных модулей. Но для windows я так и не нашла соответствующую комбинацию.
Спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для windows это должен быть ctrl + пробел, если у вас установлен плагин Python, то должны увидеть выпадающий список.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает.